# Simplifying rational expressions and not sure what to exclude

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rationalising-denominator

I am studying precalculus using Khan academy and I can't figure out why my answer isn't also correct.  We are to simplify

$\frac{x^2+6x+5}{x^2-x-2}$

First we factor:

$\frac{(x+1)(x+5)}{(x+1)(x-2)}$

And then we cancel the x+1:

$\frac{x+5}{x-2}$

The video linked below (around 7 minutes in) claims that x cannot equal -1 because the denominator would be zero in the second expression.  Apparently this is the only exclusion.   But what about x=2?  That would make both the original expression and the final simpified one undefined.  Why is -1 the correct answer (if it indeed is?)

https://youtu.be/7Uos1ED3KHI

Also - I graphed both the original and simplified expression as functions on a graphing calculator.  Both functions show an asymptote at x=2.  Doesn't that support my answer?

[image]

Comment: "*why my answer isn't also correct*" $\;-\;$ You forgot to write what the question was, exactly.

Comment: The point is that those two expressions are equal everywhere except $x=-1$, both expressions aren't defined at $x=2$ so the author didn't exclude it but obviously $x$ can't be $-2$.